помогите исправить код на Phyton
у меня есть код :
    import requests
ph = input('введите номер телефона:  ')


    spam: bool = True
    while spam:
        r = requests.post("https://api.fix-price.com/buyer/v2/registration/phone/request", data = {"phone": ph})
        if r.status_code == 400:
            print('ошибка')
            print(r)
        elif r.status_code == 200:
            print("смс отправлено")
        else:
            print('чё?')
            print(r)

Но он не работает и выдаёт ошибку line 5
spam: bool = True
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Вставьте код в вопрос как есть между тройными косыми кавычками ``` . Чтобы отредактировать вопрос, нажмите [edit] под ним. Проблема у вас с отступами, чтобы понять в чем именно - нужно видеть код точно так же, как он у вас выглядит.

Ошибка IdentationError указывает на проблему с отступами в вашем коде.
Для исправления проблемы приведите табуляцию к единому виду:
import requests as rq

phone_number = input('Phone number: ')

url = "https://api.fix-price.com/buyer/v2/registration/phone/request"

spam = True

while spam:
    r = rq.post(url, data = {"phone": phone_number})
    if r.status_code == 400:
        print('Error:', r)
    elif r.status_code == 200:
        print("Done")
    else:
        print('Another error:', r)

Вы всегда можете найти ошибку по типу в официальной документации Python :)

Если вам помог ответ, вы можете отметить его как верный
